# Druid - Distinct values of a set of columns

Tags: druid

I need distinct values of a set of dimensions from my indexes in Druid, using the REST/JSON API. Currently I am using following aggregate query (though I don't need aggregation) because I couldn't find any other  way to fetch distinct values, as all queries mandate aggregate field.

```
{
  "queryType": "groupBy",
  "dataSource": "ds1",
  "granularity": "all",
  "dimensions": ["level1","level2","level3", "val1", "val2"],
  "aggregations": [{"type": "count","name": "val2Count","fieldName": "val2"}],
  "intervals": ["2015-10-22T00:00:00.000/2015-12-22T23:00:00.000"]
}
```

1. I think this is a common scenario. Is there a way to get distinct set of columns without aggregation?
2. When I'm doing it with aggregation, how much does this aggregate affect performance (other than network IO for extra count data) over the way, if there was one without aggregation?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use select query to do the same.
http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/select-query.html

```
{
    "queryType": "select",
    "dataSource": "ds1",
    "granularity": "all",
    "descending": "true",
    "intervals": ["2016-05-01T00:00:00.000/2016-06-01T00:00:00.000"],
    "dimensions":["level1","level2","level3", "val1", "val2"],
    "pagingSpec":{"pagingIdentifiers": {}, "threshold":5}
}
```

If you have just one dimension then you may also use Lexicographic TopNMetricSpec.
http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/topnmetricspec.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the metadata query. This query will provide a cardinality estimation for every dimension.
http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/segmentmetadataquery.html
Although if you want to list all the distinct combination let say for dimension1 and dimension2, you have to use groupBy over dimension1 and dimension2. Adding a count aggregator won't really affect the performance.

Comment: metadata doesn't have distinct values for a dimension I believe

Comment: @Ashish i am sorry if you want to list all the distinct value you need to aggregate the data and use the count aggregator. Don't worry about the performance of the count aggregator, since you will have to load the data any way, The performance in this case it related to the cardinality of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same answer and after doing some testing of my own I have discovered that the following query is more performant than a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(CONCAT(level1, level2, level3, level4, level5))
FROM ds1
WHERE __time >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

^ this above is far more performant for me than the below

```
SELECT SUM("count") AS distinct_count
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS "count"
  FROM ds1
  WHERE __time >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' DAY
  GROUP BY level1, level2, level3, level4, level5
)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31360228)